# Difference between chiral and stereogenic centre?

Tags: organic-chemistry, chirality

I've seen in some books where they state all chiral centres are stereogenic centres, but not the other way around.

Is "chiral centre" related to only to optical isomerism and "stereogenic centre" related to stereoisomer in a broader sense?

Comment: Would you 1) confirm that the definitions used in your books are identical to the ones given on [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Stereocenter&oldid=807743666) 2) point out what remains unclear after reading that page?

Comment: So basically chiral center is a type of stereocentre.

Comment: So a compound can have different numbers of chiral centres and stereo centres.

Comment: Now it’s clear to me

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/59124/what-is-the-perfect-definition-for-chirality