# Is the existence of chirality center equivalent to chiral?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure, molecules, chirality

To make my question more clear, I want to ask two questions:

> 1. Is it possible for molecule to be achiral even though molecule has chirality center?
> 2. Is it possible for molecule to be chiral even though molecule doesn't have chirality center?

I thought of these questions because the definitions of chiral center and chiral do not have a one to one correspondence.

A chiral center is defined by carbon having four different ligands around it and chiral is defined by a compound being non-superimposable with its mirror image. They are quite related, but I think there will be counterexamples that satisfy one condition but not satisfy the other one.

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/59124/what-is-the-perfect-definition-for-chirality

Answer (score 6):

The answer to both questions is yes.

In regards to the first question, [meso compounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meso_compound) like tartaric acid have multiple chiral centers, but are not chiral overall because they have a mirror plane.

For the second question, a compound can be geometrically chiral without having a chiral center. A cool example class of compounds is [helicenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicene), which are helical arrangements of aromatic rings. These compounds have axial chirality, where the stereoisomers are the left and right handed versions of the helix.

Comment: A simpler example for (2) is penta-2,3-diene.  Because the methyl groups are strung out along the cumulative double bond axis, not on a single central atom, the molecular symmetry is lowered and one of the symmetry elements that goes missing is a mirror plane.